# Cant get down state to work in browser in Firewoks CS5

Tags: fireworks

can anybody help with this , I can get the 3 states to work in preview ie; up, over, down with the behaviour as onMouseOver Set Nav Bar Image.

It works in the browser if there are no links set as soon a i set a link then only up, over work not the down state , I have tried setting the links in dreamweaver but get the same result.

Is there any workaround for this this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anybody is interested , i have found out what to do

- tick the box in the properties panel that says **Show down state on load**

this does not work if you have your nav menu set as part of the master template or as a shared layer.

So you need to copy the menu to each page and set the individual button on each page with the Show down state on load tick box.

Hope this makes sense ?

thanks